# Parse PHP var_dump from Python script

Tags: php, python

How can I parse the result of var_dump in PHP? My PHP code calls a Python script as follows:

```
exec("python /home/content/51/5159651/html/perl/test_python.py $a0 $a1", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

where `$a0` and `$a1` are integers. test_python.py multiplies `$a0` and $a1 correctly, but the result `(for $a0=5 and $a1=7)` of `var_dump($output)` is

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "35" }
```

All I want is the answer, 35. Yes, I can parse the result using regex, but there must be a simpler way - e.g. something other than var_dump. The code for test_python.py is below, and I would be happy to modify it to get a simpler way to extract the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys 
parameter1=int(sys.argv[1]);
parameter2=int(sys.argv[2]);

def main(parameter1, parameter2):
    output = parameter1*parameter2
    return output

output=main(parameter1, parameter2);
print(output);
```

Comment: var dump is almost certainly not the correct mechanism to use for this

Answer (score 4):

You just need someone's phone number and you are doing a whole background check :)

```
var_dump($output);
```

Tells you everything about the response `$output`, but you just want the value. So

```
echo $output[0];   //$output is an array and you need its first element.
```

So your `var_dump` needs to go.

```
exec("python /home/content/51/5159651/html/perl/test_python.py $a0 $a1",  $output);
echo $output[0];   // will say 35 for 5 and 7
```

**A little extra**

This is the explanation of `var_dump` output

> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "35" }

That means `$output` is an array with 1 element which is on index 0. Element **type = string** and its **length = 2** and its **value = 35**

Comment: Thanks for your answer!